# cant do it SQL two table total value for display some message

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im create the  two SQL table as follows,

1. **PreCostingHeader**

   TotalEstimatedCost
2. **OderAcceptance**

   To be quoted price

**Sample Data**

```
TotalEstimatedCost 12.00
To be quoted price 30.00
```

I want to show this  message for my ASPX, but i cant do it correctly, can you please give me a example or help to the fix this

(Before Save the record whether check the pre costing value higher than order acceptance value or less than order acceptance value that show as message below.)

```
Order acceptance (Total Estimated Cost)   >     Pre costing(To be quoted Px)    Cannot be confirm the record due to Total estimated px is higher than To be quoted price 

Order acceptance (Total Estimated Cost)   <     Pre costing(To be quoted Px)    Record can be confirmed.
```

please help me to fix this,This is a ASP.net project,

Comment: What is your ask,do you want to save the record only when "Order acceptance (Total Estimated Cost)   <     Pre costing(To be quoted Px" ,if not you want to show popup ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Im using SQL saver 2012 and im write the SP